# Removing a viewcontroller by selecting a button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've created an app that contains 4 viewcontroller and its .h,.m files...In my firstviewcontroller a button is pressed it goes to secondviewcontroller and in second viewcontroller has two buttons and its used to switch back to firstviewcontroller and another button will goes to thirdviewcontroller.here is my code for firstviewcontroller.m

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

and in my secondviewcontroller for first button

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

and another button

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ThirdViewController" owner:self options:nil];
```

when i select button in firstviewcontroller it loads secondviewcontroller but in second view controller if i select any button i get Sigabart warning...

Can anyone have idea about this...I've tried so many ways..

Comment: use navigation controller for this

Comment: Is there specific requirement to navigate this way or else you can use UINavigationController as Safecase suggested.

Comment: use navigation controller as your requirment is like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following approaches to perform these tasks :

Approach 1:

In FirstViewController.m write this code at button click :

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initwithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:secondVC.view];
```

This will add the secondviewcontroller to current view

In SecondViewController.m to add third View you can write

```
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initwithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:thirdVC.view];
```

and to remove the second view you can write this:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Approach 2:

Use Navigation Controller.

Comment: If the code worked for you, then accept the answer and like it.

Answer (score 2):

use code like this

```
FirstViewController *FVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

//For Push    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:FVC animated:YES];

//For Pop
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

In iPhone app programming viewControllers are generally store in a stack one by one as we push a view controller to a new another view controller. and view remove these controller in same reverse formate. so if u want to push a new view controller use this:

> SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]
>    initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];`

and if u want to remove current view controller use this :

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] ;

if u want to jump to ur first view controller from any of the view controller

> [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

you can get the viewcontrollers presented in this stack by this line of code

> NSArray *viewArr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
>
> NSLog(@"%@",viewArr);
>
> [self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewArr objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

`

Answer (score 1):

```
//For going in forword direction you can use this block
{
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstVC animated:YES];
[firstVC relese];
}

//For returning back you can use this block
{ 
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


//But before using this line of code you have to alloc and make the property of    navigationController in your appDelegate
```

Hope this will help you